# How I can store and fetch request from moongodb from and into Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here is what I am trying to attempt. 
I have a chrome extension that I was using on my browser. I wanted to connect the extension with my `MongoDB` at `localhost`. I am not understanding how I can do that with the extension.
Here is the link to the complete extension:  [Chrome extension Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQ6rtO2VN95RmFuOG5EYXZxbXM/view?usp=sharing)
Kindly suggest me how I can connect my MongoDB with the extension? The database name is `extension` and the collection name is `Chrome`.

Comment: show us your research and what you tried so far. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Well, I have tried to edit the file from the chrome extension name :` gmail-compose.js` and tried to replace the links of the extension with my MongoDB rest API. but could see anything. Now is it helpful?

Comment: no because there is no code and we have no idea about your extension architecture.

Comment: What.... the link I have mentioned in my question has the source code of the extension. Kindly, check it.

Comment: you have enough points to know thats an invalid question format according to the guidelines. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Actually, I am a bit confused what code needs to be altered as all seems to be connected in some or the other manner. Hence, I have shared the complete extension folder, so that my points will be cleared. If you can help then it will be great.

Comment: Then its is not a good fit for this forum as it is too broad, sorry. Also, a trivial search in google for "connect to mongodb from chrome extension" shows many relevant answers and code but you havent shown to have done that research.